# Date conversion from excel into php

Tags: php, phpexcel

Hi I am using phpexcel to make some operation.

in some part of code I have a problem

```
for ($rowcount = $rowCompanyInfoStart; $rowcount <= $rowCompanyInfoEnd; $rowcount++)
            {  
                //$data = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A1:' . $maxCell['column'] . $maxCell['row']);
                $rangeCoordinates = $colCompanyInfoStart . $rowcount . ':' . $colCompanyInfoEnd . $rowcount;
                $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray($rangeCoordinates, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
                $tablo= $tablo."<tr >";

                if($rowcount !=$rowCompanyInfoStart || $rowcount != $rowCompanyInfoEnd) 
                    {

                    $UNIX_DATE = ($rowData[0][1] - 25569) * 86400;
                     $rowData[0][1]=gmdate("d/m/Y", $UNIX_DATE);

                    }

                foreach($rowData[0] as $result) 
                {  
                        $tablo= $tablo. "<td>".$result. " </td>";
                }
                $tablo= $tablo. "</tr>";
            }
```

where I want to just pass the first row and final row when I am doing date variable conversion from unix into normal conversion.
[image]

as you see second columns first row and last row is coverted also.

how can I prevent this?

```
if($rowcount !=$rowCompanyInfoStart || $rowcount != $rowCompanyInfoEnd)
```

this didn't work as it seems.

Comment: Use __AND__ not __OR__: `if($rowcount !=$rowCompanyInfoStart && $rowcount != $rowCompanyInfoEnd)`

Comment: @MarkBaker TRUE! I also realized! thank you :D